# Grep digits and character from line. Perl

Tags: regex, perl, bash, grep

This is my data:

```
@someDescription    ID    1234_Reverse_4321 ...
@someDescription    1234_4321 ...
@someDescription    ID    1234_4321 ...
```

I want to grep out these from each line:

```
1234_Reverse_4321
1234_4321
```

I use Perl but I also am familiar with bash.
I used these numbers but practically my range is from 600-5000 (but potentially can be from 0-10,000)

I wouldn't have this problem if the file was uniformly formatted with blank spaces when data is not available (line 2).

Comment: I fixed it using my own solution. Thanks for all your help! It helped me reach the solution



     @grepped = grep (/(?:\d|\d\d|\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d)(?:_|_RevStrand_)(?:\d|\d\d|\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d)/,@line);


Thanks for all your help! It helped me find my own solution

Comment: It could be shortened to: `\d+_(?:Reverse_)?\d+`

Answer (score 3):

Better use awk for this:

```
awk 'NF>2 {print $3}' file
1234_Reverse_4321
1234_4321
1234_4321
```

Comment: Can you modify this so that I can grep out all instances of this pattern in each line?

Comment: Sorry didn't get, you don't want 3rd column in output? Need a different output?

Answer (score 0):

**Purely regex:**

> [/@\w+\s+(?:ID\s+)?(\w+)/g](http://regex101.com/r/kZ3pQ8)